# I want to insert data from different tables in observation table

Tags: sql-server

OBSERVATION table-
O_ID, NAME ,OL_ID  ,BP_ID  ,OC_ID   and OL_ID  ,BP_ID  ,OC_ID these three column contain FK.

OBSERVATION_CATEGORY table-  OC_ID NAME

BUSINESS_PROCESS table- BP_ID   NAME

OPERATING_LOCATION_1 table-  ID   NAME

I have 4 other tables in which ID column is there which has to inserted in observation table. In short I have to fetch data from 4 tables into one table.

Comment: OK, so...what's the question, exactly? How to write an `INSERT` statement? How to create the relationship between your tables (you'd have to describe that)? Other?

Comment: I edited my question hope you'll get now what I'm asking. All the table have some data in it. But OBSERVATION table do not have. From all other tables I have to fetch data into OBSERVATION table. And structure of  OBSERVATION table is it contain Foreign key for last columns.

Comment: You still haven't defined where you're having difficulty. Are you unable to write an `insert` statement? Do you not understand there relationships between these tables so that you can write valid combinations to the `observation` table?

Comment: Like @alroc said, you need to ask a question here. Specifically they end in a question mark (`?`). You've explained your goals, but that doesn't tell us anything about where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

```
FIRST CREATE TABLE AND CREATE SQL QUERY LIKE below:-   
INSERT INTO table5  
SELECT O_ID,OC_ID, oc.NAME,BP_ID bp.NAME,ol.ID,ol.NAME   
FROM table1 ob INNER JOIN table2 oc ON ob.O_ID=oc.OC_ID   
INNER JOIN table3 bp ON ob.O_ID=bp.BP_ID   
INNER JOIN table4 ol ON ob.O_ID=ol.ID;  
How ever you have NOT mention your DATABASE nor your exact problem.
```